# Making a Grid to go fishing in Python

Tags: python, list, class

I'm trying to create a grid that will have a fish randomly generated and the user can select where to put a fishing line to see if they caught a fish.

I am struggling with the concept of Classes in order to make the program work. Right now I am creating a 2x2 grid and defining what needs to be in the cell, this is what I have so far.

Here is more of the skelton I am working with for this project, but right now I am trying to understand the Class cell and how to get that to work

```
import random

class Coordinate:
    '''
    '''
    def __init__(self, row, col):
        '''         
        '''
        self.row = row 
        self.col = col

    def __str__(self):
        '''
        '''
        return "(%d, %d)" %(self.row, self.col)

class Cell:
    '''
    ''' 
    def __init__(self, row, col):
        ''' 
        '''
        self.coords = Coordinate(row, col)
        self.fish = ""
        self.contains_line = False

    def contains_line(self):
        return self.contains_line

    def add_fish(self):
        self.fish = "F"

    def __str__(self):
        '''
        '''
        return 


class CarpetSea:
    '''
    '''
    num_of_fish = 0 
    total_time = 0 

    def __init__(self, N):
        '''    
        '''
        self.N = N
        N = 2
        self.grid = []
        for i in range(self.N):
            row = []
            for j in range(self.N):
                cell = Cell(i, j)
                row.append(cell)
            self.grid.append(row)

        self.available_fish = ["Salmon", "Marlin", "Tuna", "Halibut"]

    def __str__(self):
        '''
        returns a string representation of a CarpetSea, i.e. display the organized contents of each cell. 
        Rows and columns should be labeled with indices.

        Example (see "Example Run" in the PA8 specs for more):
          0  1  
        --------
        0|M |  |
        --------
        1|  |* |
        --------

        Note: call Cell's __str__() to get a string representation of each Cell in grid
        i.e. "M " for Cell at (0,0) in the example above
        '''
        return "  0  1  \n -------- \n 0| %s  | %s  | \n -------- \n 1| %s  | %s  | \n -------- "%()         
    def randomly_place_fish(self):
        '''
        randomly selects coordinates of a cell and randomly selects a fish from the available_fish list attribute. 
        Marks the cell as containing the fish.
        '''
        pass

    def drop_fishing_line(self, users_coords):
        '''
        accepts the location of the user's fishing line (a Coordinate object). 
        Marks the cell as containing the line.
        '''
        pass

    def check_fish_caught(self):
        '''
        If the cell containing the fishing line also contains a fish, returns the fish. 
        Otherwise, return False.
        '''
        pass

def main():

    main()
```

here are my instructions for the class Cell:

Cell:

**location_coords**: the location of this cell on the board (a Coordinate object).

**contains_line**: whether or not this cell contains the user's fishing line (a bool)

**fish**: the fish contained in this cell (a string)

**init**(): accepts values to assign to the attributes.

**str**(): returns a string representation of a Cell, i.e. return the contents of this cell (e.g. " " (nothing), "F" (fish), "*" (line), "F*" (fish and line)

should location_coords and fish be defined in init? or is it code in definitions in the Cell class

I am still trying to grasp everything for my final assignment in python for this semester, so I apologize if this is to big of a question for the website, I am just so desperately confused.

Comment: This seems like a bit of a stretch for using classes when the entire program could just be `import random` and `if random.random() < 0.25: print('success')`.

Comment: I think thats why this whole project is so confusing to me, because there are much more efficient ways to complete it, yet I have to follow the instructions and outline for how my teacher wants it coded... @tigerhawkT3 ..

Comment: I gave some more of my code, to show you the skelton format, but right now I am just trying to figure out how to get the Class cell to work... @TigerhawkT3 if you have any advice, I could really use some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Setting up the `Cell` class

Your `Cell` class should have attributes `coords`, `contains_line`, and `fish`. These should go in `__init__`, as you have done for the `coords` attribute. Once you have these set up, you'll be able to create cells where you can check whether they have fish or fishing lines, and so on.

A modified `__init__` with these attributes, along with extra parameters so you can set them when you create your cells might look like:

```
class Cell:
    def __init__(self, row, col, fish='', line=False):
        self.coords = Coordinate(row, col)
        self.fish = fish
        self.contains_line = line
```

We set default arguments for `fish` to be the empty string `''` (since it was specified that `fish` is a string), and `line` to be `False`, since we're presuming the game will start with no fishing lines. Other parts of the code will fill these in.

---

## Using Cells in a grid

Your grid is defined as a list of lists of cells, like

```
[[Cell, Cell],
 [Cell, Cell]]
```

Each one of these is a separate instance of the cell class. Each cell has coordinates (row, col), and just like we can access an element of a list with `list[0]`, we can access a specific cell within the grid with `grid[0][0]`.

If we pick out a specific cell, say, `selected_cell = grid[i][j]`, we can do stuff with that specific cell by calling its methods like `selected_cell.add_fish()`. For example, if we wanted to add fish to every cell, we could loop over the grid, select each cell, and run `add_fish`.

---

## Doing things with Cells

The cells' attributes are in place, now you can add logic to do other things, like add fish, check if there are fish, etc.

If for example we want to get whether the cell has a fishing line, we can check `self.contains_line`, for example:

```
def contains_line(self):
    return self.contains_line
```

We'd check by running `selected_cell.contains_line()` (assuming we have a cell called `selected_cell`).

If we want to add a fish, we could run `selected_cell.add_fish()`, with an example definition:

```
def add_fish(self):
    self.fish = 'F'
```

Comment: For the cell called this_cell, would this be defined under the Class cell or in the main function below? @David Because I probably need a variable for the cells, but I'm still trying to wrap my head around coding with Classes.

Comment: also why is it fish = ''? And should I have a bool condition for line stated in the init or its own function? @David

Comment: `this_cell` was only for example purposes. In your main function, you could do something like `cell = Cell(i, j)` then `cell.do_something()`, and so on.

Comment: `self.fish = ''` sets the initial value of the `fish` attribute to an empty string. That way, it will exist, and you can check that it contains no fish, but you can modify it later.

Comment: in my main function currently I have cell = Cell(i , j) in another class. should I define it again in my main funtion?

Comment: No, that's fine. But, whenever you want to modify the cells after you've created them, e.g. run `add_fish()`, you do it by running it on a specific cell. As in, later, when you want to add fish, you'll select a cell (say cell 1,1) with something like `selected_cell = grid[1][1]` then add this fish with `selected_cell.add_fish()`.

Comment: Your grid will be 2x2, but in order to get a specific cell from your grid (however large), you use grid[row][col]. Btw, it's a good idea to avoid adding fixes to the originally posted code, since that makes it difficult to figure out what to respond to.

Comment: oh okay! Thank you so much for all of your input! I will try to continue with the information you have given me! If I run into any major problems I will probably comment again, but thank you so much!

Comment: Sure, no problem. Happy to help!

Comment: One quick question with the __str__(self): for the class Cell, my teachers instrucntions are to 
 :

__str__(): returns a string representation of a CarpetSea, i.e. display the organized contents of each cell. Rows and columns should be labeled with indices.


should I have the organized contents of the cell their own definition? I'm just not quite sure what to return for the funtion @David

Comment: Yeah, you should have a `__str__(self)` for `Cell`, which should return a string like `return self.fish`. It should return `F` or something like that. For CarpetSea, you also need to return a string, but it's more complicated to make. First, make one row with e.g. `row_string = ' '.join([str(cell) for cell in row])`, save all rows in a list, and then combine all rows with `'\n'.join([row_string for row_string in rows])`. This will require some looping logic.

Answer (score 0):

So in general, you can initialize an object through the constructor (init() in this case) or through other methods in the class.
Sometimes objects allow both (for more flexibility). It's really up to you to decide what is more convenient.

In your case, I would say Yes, why not set the values in init()?

It does not make sense for the Cell to decide whether it has a fish or a line in it. I would have a separate class like GameEngine (or main()) have that logic. So whoever owns/creates the Cell should be able to pass it the the initial "state" values.

Later on, as the game would progress, there would be other methods in the Cell class to update its state. Maybe a fish would move to the adjacent cell if it isn't occupied by another fish?

Not sure if this is helpful to you. The whole idea of object-oriented design is that you don't lump all the code in a single method but rather design objects and assign responsibilities. Later on, as the code becomes larger and more complex, it's a lot easier to maintain it and add more features.

Comment: This does make sense, thanks! Would you say for the class Cell- that it should only really focus on creating the grid and storing the values of the fish and line, yet have the class Carpetsea decide where in the cell it goes? and if the user is correct or not? @swbandit

Comment: @sarahcampolt, yes, exactly